# Error when scaffolding using Entity Framework Core in ASP.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, .net-core

I am trying to create models using an existing SQL Server 2016 database. When the run the command prompt as shown in the documentation:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "'Server=techestatevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com;Database=Blogging;User Id=newuser;Password=pass;'" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -verbose
```

I get this error:

> Working directory: E:\Personal\TE\VS Projects\EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb\src\EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb
>   Executing command: dotnet ef --configuration Debug --build-base-path .\bin\ dbcontext scaffold ''Server=techestatevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com;Database=Blogging;User Id=newuser;Password=pass;''
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --verbose
>   At line:1 char:215
>   + ... user;Password=pass;'' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --verbo ...
>   +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
>   Unexpected token 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' in expression or statement.

I have added all the Nuget packages. See my `project.json` :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a documentation issue. The suggestion caution as mentioned in the doc is the culprit. Removing the outer double quotes fixed the issue.

Note that the connection string is double quoted (with single quotes inside the double quotes). This is a workaround for a known issue in RC2 for more details.